# Как в GameObject.SetActive(bool) передать параметр отрицательного значения в Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity3d

На сцене у меня есть `GameObject Cube`, а еще есть код, при котором куб "отключается" при нажатии на клавишу D. Вот так примерно:

```
   if (Input.KetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)) 
   {
       Cube.SetActive(false);
   }
```

Но я хочу, чтобы куб отключался и включался на эту же клавишу, в теории нужно, чтобы, каждый раз нажимая на D, SetActive принимал параметр текущего противоположного по знаку значения, но как написать этот параметр понятия не имею

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться свойством [GameObject.activeSelf](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html):

```cs
Cube.SetActive(!Cube.activeSelf);
```